# IOS: crash when exit from a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, memory-management

I have a strange problem: in my app I have a scrollview where are 20 buttons; with these buttons you can open a secondviewcontroller; if you push a button (example first button) it open secondviewcontroller with an image, if you push another button it open secondviewcontroller but with another image; my problem is that after 20 (about) times that I open secondviewcontroller my app crash and the message is

```
-[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x180200
```

but I don't know what is the problem; inside secondviewcontroller I dealloc all the resource.

Comment: Can you show your code that is used to push the second view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code is definitely going to help.  That being said, this sounds like it could be a memory issue.  Run the application though Instruments and check for allocations and leaks.